# Не запускается сервер Django что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

## Не запускает сервер Django

Начал учить Django по видео ХаудиХО

Вот ссылка на видео : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4nrT7emiVc

Все делал как там и на моменте создания приложения articles при запуске сервера ошибка.
Кто знает что это ? и как исправить ? помогите пожалуйста.

Ошибка :

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'
Traceback (most recent call last):

for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DJ\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 380, in snapshot_files

resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1204, in resolve
s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))

OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома:
<frozen importlib._bootstrap

### Использования модуля articles

urls.py (Файл в папке с проектом)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

### Весь код

urls.py (В папке articles)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

urls.py (Файл в папке с проектом)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

wsgi.py (Файл в приложении)

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mablog.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py (Файл в папке с проектом и с патчем) + Были добавлены фрагменты кода которые были добавлены или  видоизменённые

```
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',  ]
```

Comment: Очевидно, у вас почему-то не существует модуль articles. Как исправить — или взять этот модуль откуда-нибудь, или прекратить его использование в коде

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста,вот где он у меня используется

Comment: Файл `articles/__init__.py` не забыли создать?

Comment: Нет, файл есть  articles/__init__.py

Comment: Попробуйте в INSTALLED_APPS добавить 'articles':

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....,
    ....,
    ....,
    'articles',
]

Comment: Давайте ссылку на Гит.

Comment: Уже пробовал так делать в INSTALLED_APPS = [ ...., ...., ...., 'articles', ]  , ничего не получилось ошибка идентична начальной

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вам показывает на то-что она не видит папку `articles`
Так как вы забили зарегистрировать своё WEB-приложения в `settings.py`
Для того чтобы исправить ошибку всего добавьте в конец списка `INSTALLED_APPS`
Такую строчку:
`'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',`
После этого так должно выглядеть:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',  
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',   ]
```

Comment: Наличие записи в INSTALLED_APPS никак не поможет увидеть эту папку

Comment: Покрайне мере, это уже одна допущена ошибка у создателя вопроса в коде.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ но ошибка полностью все та же осталась